# Wordpress Featured Image Link

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-featured-image

I have 9 posts showing up on a page. I'm only showing the featured images from the post and the images are set to a background image. I want to be able to click the images and have the image show up in a new window. I'm having a little trouble figuring this out. I want to wrap the div in an link.

This is the code I have:

```
<article <?php post_class('col-md-4 site-content'); ?>>

<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( 
$post->ID ), 'large' );
$image = $image[0]; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="coupons-post" style="background-image: url('<?php echo  
$image; ?>')">
            <?php /*?><div class="entry-thumbnail">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php 
the_post_thumbnail('large' , array( 'class' => 'img-responsive') ); ?></a>
            </div><?php */?>
           <!-- <div class="post-content">
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <p class="date">News / <?php the_time('n.j.Y') ?></p>
                </div>
                <h2 class="entry-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </h2>

                <div class="entry-summary">
                    <p></p><p><?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                            <?php echo substr($excerpt, 0, 100); ?>...</p>
                    <p></p>
                    <a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>-->
      </div>

</article>
```

I want to wrap the div "coupons-post" with the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
<article <?php post_class('col-md-4 site-content'); ?>>

<?php 
    if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' );
        $image = $image[0];
    }
?>

    <a href="<?= $image; ?>" target="_blank">
        <div class="coupons-post" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image; ?>')">
        </div>
    </a>
</article>
```